# Create two enum with identical 0 values

Tags: enums, scope, compiler-construction, vxworks

I want to create two enums with identical 0 (default values), which looks like:

```
enum testone_e    {
    NOCHANGE = 0,
    DOONETHING,
    BLABLA
};

enum testtwo_e    {
    NOCHANGE = 0,
    DOANOTHERTJHING,
} ;
```

but the compiler complains about:
 **"NOCHANGE" has already been declared in the current scope**

why that, isn't that two different scopes (as the values are in different enums)..? How do I solve this best?
This is with WindRiver's `diab` compiler

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In C, all enumeration constants are `int`s in the global scope. (More accurately, in the scope of the `enum` itself, which is usually file scope.)

So you can only define each name once.